# Getting error "TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests" while running test

Tags: java, kotlin, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I am trying to run tests with Junit 5 in my maven project but getting error : `TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests` . junit-jupiter-engine version is 5.9.0 (tried other versions as well) and maven-surefire-plugin version is 2.22.2.

I am using Intellij Community Edition (2023.1.3) with

Getting following error:

```
rg.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:189)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:168)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/jupiter/api/ClassOrderer
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.config.DefaultJupiterConfiguration.<clinit>(DefaultJupiterConfiguration.java:50)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 11 more
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>Airline</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>consoleApp</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <kotlin.code.style>official</kotlin.code.style>
        <kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>1.8</kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>
        <kotlin.version>1.9.0</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mavenCentral</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <source>src/main/kotlin</source>
                                <source>target/generated-sources/annotations</source>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <source>src/test/kotlin</source>
                                <source>target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations</source>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>MainKt</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I tried changing the version for junit-jupiter-engine but that didn`t help. Could anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your pom, you have the following dependencies:

- `kotlin-test-junit5:1.7.10` depends on `junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0`
- `junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2` depends on `junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2`

And class `org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer` was only introduced in `junit-jupiter-api:5.8.0`.

So here you have 2 dependencies that both have a transitive dependency to `junit-jupiter-api`, however they depend on different version. Maven has an algorithm to resolve this version conflict, and I think it decides to use `junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2` (as it's explicitly brought in by your pom) with `junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0` (* see note 1 at the bottom) – this can be checked using `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and see what it says.

In order to solve this conflict, I'd simply remove `junit-jupiter-engine` from your pom, as it's brought in by `kotlin-test-junit5` anyway. This should solve the problem I think.

As a side note, you can use the [Maven Enforcer plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/), which has goals to ensure all dependencies (including transitive ones) [converge](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) to the same version.

Notes:

1. I think that's because it's a transitive dependency with depth 1 in both `kotlin-test-junit5` and `junit-jupiter-engine`, however `kotlin-test-junit5` comes first, so that's the version that ends up being used.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the Message was: `TestEngine with ID 'junit-plattform-engine' failed to discover tests`
It is a different version but might be related, the problem was not the configuration itself, but a *.feature-File with text in it that was not gherkin style.

Somewhere in the surefire dump was a hint to the feature file where the parsing went wrong.